# PropertyChanged event fires twice and should not

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a class with two descendent classes (child, grandchild):

```
BaseSample
   |-ProcessData
       |-Measurement
```

When a property changes in the Measurement class I raise a OnCrucibleOxidizedMassChanged event:

```
Protected Sub AddEventHandler(ByVal thisMeasurement As CalcinerDataAccess.O2Measurement)

    AddHandler thisMeasurement.PropertyChanged, AddressOf RaiseMassChanged

End Sub

Protected Sub RaiseMassChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim CrucibleOxidizedMassReadyToReport As Boolean = _
        (TypeOf e Is System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) AndAlso _
        (CType(e, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs).PropertyName = "CrucibleOxidizedMass" And _
            CType(sender, CalcinerDataAccess.O2Measurement).CrucibleOxidizedMass IsNot Nothing)

    If CrucibleOxidizedMassReadyToReport Then
        RaiseEvent OnCrucibleOxidizedMassChanged(sender, e)

    End If

End Sub
```

For testing purposes, I have a module that tests this event-raising behavior. Note that ToteBinSample inherits from the BaseSample.  In Main() I'm just testing what happens when you change the value of CrucibleOxidizedMass:

```
Sub Main()


    thisSample = New SampleTypeManager.SampleTypes.ToteBinSample
    AddHandler thisSample.OnCrucibleOxidizedMassChanged, AddressOf OnChanged

    thisSample.SampleData.ProcessDatas(0).O2Measurements(0).CrucibleOxidizedMass = 20

    Console.WriteLine("Done...")
    Console.Read()


End Sub

Private Sub OnChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Console.WriteLine("Time to send report!")

End Sub
```

However, the OnChanged sub **gets called twice**, even though I only assign a value to CrucibleOxidizedMass once.

Do you have any idea why it gets fired twice and how I can correct it?

Comment: Can you show where you are raising the initial event.

Comment: msarchet: In the Sub Main(), when I assign the value of 20 to the CrucibleOxidizedMass property, this should fire the PropertyChanged event in the Measurement class.  In this class I delegated the PropertyChanged event to the RaiseMassChanged sub, which should raise the OnCrucibleOxidizedMassChanged under the right conditions.  It is this event that should cause the OnChanged sub in the module to be called (and print "Time to send report!" only once).  Hope this clarifies my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.  I manually raised the PropertyChanged event within the OnCrucibleOxidizedMassChanged sub of the LINQ to SQL class, O2Measurement. So, I was causing the second firing of the PropertyChanged event.  Thanks, msarchet, and any others who pondered this problem.

```
Partial Class O2Measurement

    Private Sub OnCrucibleOxidizedMassChanged()
        'Here is my mistake -- I have removed it in my code
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("CrucibleOxidizedMass"))

    End Sub
End Class
```